# Month/Year Format in Latex

Tags: datetime

This should be a easy question, but I didn't find answer from googling. The date format I wan is: Month(letter), Year(numerical). For example, I want: November, 2014. Of course, I can manually achieve this requirement. But I think LaTeX can do better. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to use it? Do you want to specify it using a regular date-like format, yet LaTeX should output it using (only) "Month, Year"? As in, `\mydate{2014/11/14}` should output `November, 2014`?

Comment: Thanks Werner for the swift reply! I am not sure how to specify it, but the ultimate output I want is: month, year. For example: November, 2014. If I put \date{\today}, it will contain date which I do not want.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) package to customize the formatting; a little complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\monthyeardate\today

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 31):

With `datetime2` package, there is at least two ways to achieve this. The first is a bit similar to [the answer by Gonzalo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212264/80030):

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\monthyeardate}{%
  \DTMenglishmonthname{\@dtm@month}, \@dtm@year
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\monthyeardate

\end{document}
```

[image: datetime2 the first way]

The other way, I think, is more LaTeXian:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\today

\DTMlangsetup{showdayofmonth=false}
\today
\DTMlangsetup{showdayofmonth=true}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image: datetime2 the second way]

Some notes:

- For the first way to work, `english` parameter for `\documentclass` seems to be required. Alternatively, `english` can be omitted and `en-US` or `en-GB` given for `datetime2` as `\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}`
- The second way *requires* `en-US` or `en-GB` even when `english` has been given for `\documentclass`.
- The ways were tested with `pdflatex`, version pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015).

More details are provided in:

- [datetime2 documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf)
- [datetime2-english documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-english/datetime2-english.pdf)

Comment: This seems to be outdated. One way to get it in the new paradigm is `\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}`, then `\DTMsavenow{mytoday}` and then `\DTMmonthname{\DTMfetchmonth{mytoday}}~\DTMfetchday{mytoday}, \DTMfetchyear{mytoday}` (obviously, leave out the fetching of the day if you don't want that).

Answer (score 22):

A simple solution that requires no extra packages is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\today}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
December\fi, \number \year} 

\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion.

Comment: This is the worst answer, in my opinion.

Comment: Both of your comments are not helpful, in my opinion, as they don't say 'why'

Comment: I would propose to simply create a new command rather than redefining \today

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy for people new to Latex, I shall add a cw answer here incorporating Atiyah Elsheikh's comment on luchonacho's answer (this seems to be the best of both worlds to me).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\monthyeardate}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
December\fi, \number \year} 

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\monthyeardate}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Correct me if this is totally wrong. I am not a TeXnician.