# Removing "de" preposition in Month/Year date format

Tags: datetime

I want to have the date of my document with a Month/Year format such as "May 2016". To accomplish this I have followed the instructions in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212264/98306) and [this article](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/customize-the-date-format-in-your-latex-documents/).

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\monthyeardate\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

However, since my document is written in Catalan, when I compile it, the date contains the "de" preposition as you can see in the following picture:

[image: date with "de" preposition]

This preposition is completely unnecessary and should not appear, so for instance, the date should read "maig 2016".

The default date construction is: "15 de maig de 2016", see how the number 15 and the right-hand side "de" preposition are correctly removed, but not the left-hand side "de".

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you need the date at any later point in the document? If not, try `\date{maig 2016}`.

Comment: There's `datetime2` as well, but I can't say whether that's easier to use

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for your comment. Not really, I only need the date at the top of my document. So I guess your solution is the simplest way of staying out of trouble :) However, hardcoding stuff is usually a bad practice.

Comment: It is part of the title, there is nothing wrong in hardcoding the title. You title and your name are also hard coded ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B What if I edit the document next month? If the title and the authors stay the same that's ok, but will the date change automatically? ;-)

Comment: Well, ok. If you put it that way. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very elementary approach, with an `\ifcase...` statement and the `month` and `year` count registers. This is not hardcoded then (except the month names in `\monthcatalan` ;-)

The `day`, `month` and `year` registers are always available and can be printed with `\the\day` etc. By default, they return the date reported by the OS.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\monthcatalan#1{%
  \ifcase#1
  \or gener%
  \or febrer%
  \or març%
  \or abril%
  \or meig%
  \or juny%
  \or juliol%
  \or agost%
  \or setembre%
  \or octubre%
  \or novembre%
  \or deciembre%
  \fi
}



\title{Title}
\author{Author}


\date{\monthcatalan{\month} \the\year}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```