# datetime2: define and explicitely use date formats

Tags: datetime2

As `datetime` is superseded by `datetime2`, I'm struggling hard to achieve the following using the new package:

In an English document, I would like to show the current date (`\today`) once like this *20th December 2017* and once like this *2017-12-20*.

According to the documentation, I get it right only one way globally for the whole document. I didn't find a simple example showing me how to get this done.

The answer given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250057 fiddles with `\@dtm@month` etc. Is it that hard? It should be simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define a new format. You can use one of the regional English day-month formats, such as `en-GB`, for the textual date and `iso` for the numeric ISO-style date:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=level}

\begin{document}
\today. \DTMsetstyle{iso}\today.

\end{document}
```

Requires that both `datetime2` and [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) are installed.

[image: 20th December 2017. 2017-12-20.]

Answer (score 3):

In sake of coming up with a short example, I solved it myself:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showdow,en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\DTMnewdatestyle{myShortDate}{%
\renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\number##1-\number##2-\number##3}%
\renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\DTMnewdatestyle{myLongDate}{%
\renewcommand*{\DTMenglishfmtordsuffix}{\DTMenGBfmtordsuffix}%
\renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMenglishordinal{##3}\ \DTMenglishmonthname{##2}\ \number##1}%
\renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}


\begin{document}
{\DTMsetdatestyle{myShortDate}\today}\par
\today\par
{\DTMsetdatestyle{myLongDate}\today}\par
\end{document}
```

Though it is not as short as Nicola Talbot's answer