# Removing date while preserving month and year from \today?

Tags: datetime, date

I wish to format today's date as `october 2022`. Emphasis on the lowercase `october`. I know that `\today` gives me `October 24, 2022`. How can I extract just the month and the year? I tried using `\the\month \the\year` but that gives me `10 2022`. Is there a short command to convert numeric month to words?

I am also aware that I can use the `datetime` package to format dates. The following snippet from [statatexblog.com](https://statatexblog.com/2021/10/18/add-date-month-or-year-to-your-latex-document/) kinda works. However, it gives me `October 2022`. I am unable to convert `October` to lowercase `october`. Neither `\MakeLowercase` nor `\lowercase` seems to work. Is there a workaround?

```latex
\documentclass[english,a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\begin{document} 
The current month is \MakeLowercase{\monthyeardate\today} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I ended up using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671660/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `\lcmonth` gives the lowercased month name.  An optional argument of a number will give the lowercased month name associated with the number.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article} 
\newcommand\lcmonth[1][\the\month]{\ifcase#1
  \or
  january\or 
  february2\or
  march\or
  april\or
  may\or
  june\or
  july\or
  august\or
  september\or
  october\or
  november\or
  december\fi}
\begin{document} 
The current month is \lcmonth\ \the\year.

\lcmonth[6]
\end{document}
```

[image]